Android 10 can not create passkey (react native app)
I'm facing issue with react-native-passkey lib
on document said "Native Passkeys on iOS 15.0+ and Android API 28+ using React Native."
I'm building .apk file which config passkey as document.


  async function createAccount() {

    //generate a challenge from backend
    try {
      const requestJson = {
        'challenge': 'T1xCsnxM2DNL2KdK5CLa6fMhD7OBqho6syzInk_n-Uo',
        'rp': {
          'name': 'Passkey',
          'id': 'com.myapp',
        },
        'user': {
          'id': 'user123',
          'name': 'john.doe@example.coms',
          'displayName': 'john Does',
        },
        'pubKeyCredParams': [
          {
            'type': 'public-key',
            'alg': -7,
          },
        ],
        'authenticatorSelection': {
          'authenticatorAttachment': 'platform',
          'requireResidentKey': true,
          'userVerification': 'preferred',
        },
        'timeout': 60000,
        'attestation': 'direct',
      };


      const result = await Passkey.create(requestJson);

      console.log('Registration result: ', result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Registration result:',e);
   
    }
  }



I was testing on 3 devices.
1st is android 14, it can create passkey as expected.
but my 2nd and 3rd device are android 10. I'm unable to create passkey and got error as {"error": "Native error", "message": "Error: The incoming request cannot be validated"}
Do you know how to fix?

So I just change rp.id on requestJson to my domain from https://mydomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json
like
 'rp': {
      'name': 'Passkey',
      'id': 'mydomain',
    },

